# How to use Room with AIDE?

Tags: android, android-room, aide-ide

I added the component libraries to my gradle files, as explained here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#2

But AIDE still doesn't resolve imports:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

I've also tried this way:

```
dependencies {
    // Room components
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

AIDE doesn't resolve

```
import androidx
```

It simply does't react on any changes in the gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as per bellow

```
dependencies {
    // Room components
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried. Didn't help. And how to apply the changes? Should I restart AIDE? The phone? How can I be sure that the change are applied. AIDE just doesn't react in any way.

Comment: after adding those dependency you get synch button in your gradle where you can click and synch the gradle file.

Comment: Where is it? I can't see any synch button! Can you post some screenshots please.

Comment: Updated my answer you can check

Comment: oh, it's Android Studio. My question is related to AIDE - IDE for tablets. Anyways thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the premium version, go to settings.  where it says *path to android.jar* put a reference to a recent android.jar ( This is usually comes bundled with android studio) you could download it from the net.
Also after adding dependencies , you just always go to settings and click on Refresh Maven repositories under Build settings.